# Write dataframe to excel with a title

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, xlsx

I would like to print out a dataframe in Excel. I am using ExcelWriter as follows:

```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('test.xlsx')
df = DataFrame(C,ind)    # C is the matrix and ind is the list of corresponding indices 
df.to_excel(writer, startcol = 0, startrow = 5)
writer.save()
```

This produces what I need but in addition I would like to add a title with some text (explanations) for the data on top of the table (`startcol=0` ,`startrow=0`).

How can I add a string title using ExcelWriter?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You should be able to write text in a cell with the [write_string](http://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.org/worksheet.html#write_string) method, adding some reference to *XlsxWriter* to your code:

```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('test.xlsx')
df = DataFrame(C,ind)    # C is the matrix and ind is the list of corresponding indices 
df.to_excel(writer, startcol = 0, startrow = 5)

worksheet = writer.sheets['Sheet1']
worksheet.write_string(0, 0, 'Your text here')

writer.save()
```

Comment: Thanks a million Fabio. I tried to use write_string but got some errors for wrong implementation. Now it works perfectly.

Answer (score 5):

This will do the trick:

```
In[16]: sheet = writer.sheets['Sheet1'] #change this to your own
In[17]: sheet.write(0,0,"My documentation text")
In[18]: writer.save()
```

Comment: Thanks Yannis for your comment. Cheers.